# Unbinding click handlers on certain classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, event-handling

I have a table cell that I want to be able to be clicked. But once it is clicked it will have the class ".clicked". When any table cell has this class, I do not want to be clickable. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done by inserting some code at the top of the event handler.

```
$('td').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    // the rest of your code here
});
```

The other, more involved, way, is to use event delegation and only fire the function if the element doesn't have the class when it's clicked:

```
$('table').on('click', 'td:not(.clicked)', function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method to unbind any events.

```
$('td').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('clicked').off('click');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event registration method to do it, it will un-register the handler once the event is fired.

```
$('td').one('click', function(){
    console.log('hanlded', this)
})
```

Another solution could be

```
$('table').on('click', ':not(.clicked)', function(){
    console.log('hanlded', this)
})
```

Comment: I considered this, but I want it to be clickable again if it were to lose the class ".clicked" later in the code and that would make this goal impossible.

Comment: The downvoter isn't me. But note that you really need `td:not(.clicked)`, otherwise it will match on other types of elements as well, which will lead to unpredictable behaviour where `this` may not be the `td`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `:not(.clicked)` to whatever selector you're using to exclude clicked cells.

Comment: No, that won't work. Whether `.clicked` is present will change during the life of the document, whereas this function won't.

Comment: sorry, i assumed you were using event delegation

Comment: Well, yeah, it works if you use delegation, as I show in my answer. But there's nothing in the OP to suggest they are.